# How to compute the limit of the following complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble in computing the limit of the first order derivative of the complex function 
$\frac{z^2}{(\frac{e^z}{z+1}-1)^2}$ at $z=0$:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dz}[\frac{z^2}{(\frac{e^z}{z+1}-1)^2}]=?$$

How to determine whether or not this limit exists? (And, if the limit exists, what is the value of the limit ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. We have
$$
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2}{\left(\frac{e^z}{z+1}-1\right)^2} = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2(z+1)^2}{\left({e^z}-z-1\right)^2}
$$Using the Maclaurin series, $e^z\approx 1+z+z^2/2$; then the denominator is $O(z^4)$ while the numerator is $O(z^2)$ for $z\to0$. If the limit of the function doesn't exist, the limit of its derivative doesn't exist either.

Comment: In the last line of your proof you assert that if the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}g(z)$ doesn't exist, then the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}g'(z)$ doesn't exist either. Can you give a reference or sketch the proof of this fact?

Comment: In general this isn't true, but it is if you have a singularity. The function divides by $0$ at $z=0$, so the derivative does as well.